# GIF type high quality video clips in wikihow

Tags: video, gif

[wikihow high quality video clips/gifs](https://www.wikihow.com/Store-Bananas)

In this page, I'm not sure whether these moving images are gifs or videos exactly? They are high quality and plays in a loop like gifs and also has very low file size.

Is there any special way to make these? Also in wiki it doesn't show the media player either. This is a perfect high quality GIF!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any special way to make these? Also in Wiki it doesn't show the media player either. 
>  This is a perfect high quality GIF!

Those are not GIF, they are actually MP4 video files. To avoid media controls just remove the command `controls` from your `<video>` tag setup. To auto-replay the clip(s) just add `loop`.

You can read more about `<video>` tag's [options at **this link**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#Attributes).

**Example**: Test this code and let me know if it gives expected result...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<!-- Video #1 -->

<video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
<source src="https://www.wikihow.com/video/d/d0/Store%20Bananas%20Step%201%20Version%202.360p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<!-- Video #2 -->

<video width="320" height="240" autoplay loop>
<source src="https://www.wikihow.com/video/8/8f/Store%20Bananas%20Step%202%20Version%202.360p.mp4">
</video>

<br> The above clips are MP4 video files, not animated GIF images.

</body>
</html>
```